# Seeking alternative version of "The Monkey's Paw"

Tags: story-identification

The classic horror story "[The Monkey's Paw](https://americanliterature.com/author/w-w-jacobs/short-story/the-monkeys-paw)" by [W. W. Jacobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._W._Jacobs) recounts the story of a family that receives a magic mummified paw that grants three wishes.  However, the way the wishes turn out to work is far from optimal.

The funny thing is, I first heard (most of) a very different version of this story, which I would like to locate again.  It was told aloud (perhaps beside a campfire), and the nature of the paw was very similar.  It was supposed to grant three wishes, but they did not work out the way they wanted.

In the version I heard, a rich miser gets ahold of the magic paw somehow, and he wishes for a gold bar.  Promptly, the next night, his office building burns down, and all the gold in his safe gets melted together into a single bar.  There is evidence that the fire was started by somebody inside the factory.  So he uses his second wish to go back in time to keep an eye of things that night.  Naturally, he accidentally knocks over his kerosene lamp and starts the fire himself.

And that's all I heard of the story.  I'm not sure if there was an interruption, or I had to leave, or what.  But I never heard about the third wish, and I'd like to know how it ended.

It's possible that this story was invented by the teller (as a further elaboration of the monkey paw motif), or that it existed otherwise only in the oral tradition of campfire storytellers, but I rather doubt it.  If there is a written version (which may differ in substantial ways from what I have described), I would like to find it.